# Tuning historical rebalance

Tags: ignite

I try to applied config to use historical rebalance, but it seem does not working properly. I increase `setMaxWalArchiveSize`, but after applied new `setMaxWalArchiveSize`, our node sometimes automatically shuts down.

Does anyone have experience with this process?

Comment: Can you please provide an error message that you observe when the node shuts down?